# How to launch robot_localization nodes?

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**GOAL**

I want to use a node from this package (EKF node) with one of its possible inputs (IMU).

**PROBLEM**

Using this package: About this package: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization

I can't launch the node because of missing yaml code (?). The documentation mentions no yaml code, except for a totally different node I'm not touching. I also cannot find the source code of the node, to take a look inside. The documentation doesn't help in explaining how to specify a particular type of input, either.

```
p@t:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization/launch$ ls -a
.  ..  dual_ekf_navsat_example.launch  ekf_template.launch  navsat_transform_template.launch  ukf_template.launch
```

there is no ekf node to launch, but there is a template and an example. Let me try those:

```
p@t:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization$ roslaunch robot_localization ekf_template.launch
... logging to /home/p/.ros/log/5f5b9924-d910-11e7-9476-446d57e0983f/roslaunch-turing-20380.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
error loading <rosparam> tag: 
    file does not exist [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization/params/ekf_template.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/ekf_template.yaml"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

and also:

```
p@t:/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization$ roslaunch robot_localization dual_ekf_navsat_example.launch
... logging to /home/p/.ros/log/5f5b9924-d910-11e7-9476-446d57e0983f/roslaunch-turing-20735.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

error loading <rosparam> tag: 
    file does not exist [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/robot_localization/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/dual_ekf_navsat_example.yaml"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

so I can't find how to launch the EKF node, and I also can't launch any example nodes, because i'm missing yaml?

I'm new at ROS, but I've done the tutorials. Please help me. What am I missing, besides a brain?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277483/how-to-launch-robot_localization-nodes?/) by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-06**:
Can you please copy and paste the terminal output into your question? Images are not searchable while text is.

**Comment by [pedro1713](https://answers.ros.org/users/32895/pedro1713/) on 2017-12-06**:
Follow the git link about in the middle of the webpage you link to, that will take you to the project github page where you can check the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at https://answers.ros.org/question/206043/ekf_localization-with-gps-and-imu/ for an answer including a very complete launch file. No yaml file used.
Also I recommend spending at least 15 minutes with this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfvvpYBAMww

---

Originally posted by [pedro1713](https://answers.ros.org/users/32895/pedro1713/) with karma: 26 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on 2017-12-09**:
I'd already seen the video, however, I'm still unable to understand how to launch the nodes.

This package comes with ekf and ukf nodes, right? This video goes into great detail how to build up an ekf node in c++, but what I want to know is how to launch the one that already exists. And I cant.